# Unable to access Session State from class?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-state

I have a Dynamic Data application to which I have added a class for extending EDM. Everything works great, but now I am trying to set an entity property value equal to a value in session state - and its not recognizing the Session command. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
audit.action_by = CStr(Session("person_name"))
```

I think this is because I do not have the class Inheriting Page, but if I do add Inherits Page it breaks other stuff. How can I have the class include the ability to utilize sessions directly without inheriting Page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session("person_name")
```

Comment: Make sure you test `HttpContext.Current` for `null` first.  I'm not sure how the class is used, but if it's ever utilized outside the request/response scope, the context could be null.

Answer (score 3):

The `Session` property of the `Page` and `UserControl` classes is just a shortcut for `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Answer (score 0):

if HttpContext.Current.Session is not working,than use  like this System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session